# Structural types as NTTP: why must all members be public?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

In the following example

```
template<auto V>
struct A {};

struct B {
    constexpr B(int a) : value{a} {}
private:
    int value{0};
};

int main() {
    constexpr B b{0};
    A<b> t2;        
}
```

the member `value` has to be public to make the type `B` structural to use it as NTTP for `A`.

So, no type with private members to be used as NTTP? 
Is this the real intent of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html ?

Comment: A defaulted `operator<=>` is no longer necessary

Comment: That is not the question and also not the cause.

Comment: I wasn't anwering your question. Just wanted to point out that neither the `<compare>` header nor the defaulted `operator <=>` are necessary for NTTP to work according to the c++ draft in its current form. Therefore, they are unnecessary in your test case.

Comment: Ok. I edited the example.

Comment: For those who are wondering what NTTP are - those are Non-Type Template Parameters.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is this the real intent of [P1907]?

The intent of P1907 is to properly specify what it means for two values to be *equivalent* in a template parameter context. Prior to this paper, the notion of equivalence was first based on `<=>` ([P0732](https://wg21.link/p0732)) and then based on `==` ([P1185](https://wg21.link/p1185)), but using those comparison operators as a foundation has a lot of issues (as described in the paper).

Consider pointers. We already have had for a long time the ability to write:

```
template <char const*> struct X { };
```

And here, `X<p>` and `X<q>` are the *same type* if the pointers `p` and `q` point to the same object with static storage duration or both null pointers (P1907 also allowed the ability for both to be past-the-end pointers or both to the same subobject).

Now, consider a type like:

```
struct S {
    char const* b;
    char const* e;
    char const* c;
};
```

How would:

```
template <S> struct Y { };
```

work? This type has all public members, so it's safe to say that it has no invariants - anyone can modify any of these pointers to point to anything. The rules are then that `Y<s1>` and `Y<s2>` are the same type if `s1.b` and `s2.b` are the same pointer, and if `s1.e` and `s2.e` are the same pointer, and if `s1.c` and `s2.c` are the same pointer. All three pairwise are the same.

Now consider a type like:

```
class String {
private:
    char const* begin_;
    char const* end_;
    char const* capacity_;

public:
    constexpr String();
    constexpr String(char const*);
    constexpr String(String const&);
    constexpr String& operator=(String const&);
    constexpr ~String();
};
```

This type has private members, and as such, enforces some invariants - and likely has a different understand of what "same" must mean than simply "all of its members are pairwise equivalent." Indeed, `String` is roughly how `std::string` looks (ignoring SSO), and if we took the approach of memberwise-equivalent then we'd run into situations where given:

```
template <String> struct Z { };
```

`Z<"hello"s>` might give a different type each time - since we have to allocate storage to hold the string, and those underlying pointers might be different. A not-insignificant driver of P1907 was that it's desirable to eventually allow:

```
template <std::string> struct C;
```

Such that `C<"hello">` is not only consistently the same type within a translation unit but also consistently the same type across *all* translation units. And the mechanisms based on `<=>`/`==` would not work for that case. And the only way to get `std::string` to properly work as a non-type template parameter is to be able to have a customization mechanism where the author of `std::string` specifies what the equivalence is based on -- in this case, we wouldn't even look at the capacity pointer at all, it would just be based on the sequence of characters from `begin_` to `end_` (not the pointer values, the pointed-to values).

That new mechanism doesn't exist yet (the authors have hinted at an `operator template`), so before it exists there were two choices:

1. remove all class types as non-type template parameters
2. come up with a default mechanism that works for some types but won't add an *incorrect* notion of equivalence to other types, even if that prevents using some class types as non-type template parameters from which the member-wise equivalent rule would be correct.

We went with option 2, using "all public" as the mechanism for doing simple, member-wise equivalence... with the understanding that C++23 will have such a mechanism (like `operator template`) to allow for non-type template parameters of types like `std::string`, `std::vector<char>`, `std::optional<int>`, etc.

Comment: "*And the mechanisms based on <=>/== would not work for that case.*" Could you elaborate a bit on why that would not work? It seems to me that some hypothetical `operator template` function would basically be doing what a `constexpr operator==` would do: test all of the characters in the strings for equality. Is it that you sometimes want them to do different things, or is it a `constexpr` issue, or something else?

Comment: @NicolBolas: The `operator template` would **identify** the characters in a format that the compiler understood and could mangle for linking; a user-written `operator==` would *examine* them, but couldn’t in general be used to determine what needed to be included in the identity.

Comment: P1097R0 says that the compile-time result of opartor== could be different from the run-time result (type A inconsistency). Can anyone give an example where this happens? I can't imagine such a situation.

Comment: @wimalopaan The paper gives multiple examples.

Comment: Well, I can't get the point, sorry: In the paper it reads "(A) The run-time result of x == y differs from the compile-time result of std::is_same_v<A<x>, A<y>> for a suitably chosen template A." But no exampe for x oder y are given. I would be very happy to see a very simple example.

Comment: @wimalopaan The paper gives the following examples: pointer-to-member types, floating-point types, references, and types with user-defined operator==.

Comment: @Barry. Ok, I see the problems with user-defined op==. But why was the decision to force all members to be public?

Comment: Yes, but I still don't see the point or a simple example (no dynamic alloc) example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, yet disappointing: C++20 will not allow this. Eventually c++23 will introduce a broader solution ...

Comment: Hopefully C++23 doesn't need to. With luck, we ought to have `constexpr` function parameters, which I would hope virtually eliminates the need for significant class NTTP support.

Comment: Is there a paper describing this (constexpr function parameters)?. Ist this for C++20. Where do you see the relationship to the above problem?

Comment: "*Is there a paper describing this (constexpr function parameters)?*" [Here](https://wg21.link/P1045) "*Ist this for C++20.*" No. "*Where do you see the relationship to the above problem?*" Most of the times I have wanted a NTTP that is a complex type, it's because I'm using template metaprogramming to do something we *ought* to be able to do with a regular function call. With `constexpr` function parameters, I no longer need to use template parameters to pass literal types in a `constexpr` form around to a function.